# Jquery plugin for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm new at Jquery plugins and Im still trying to figure out how to make my plugin work with multiple elements, after searching tutorials and questions made around the web I realised that plugin coding depends a lot on what your plugin is about, so it might be hard to find a template for a specific solution.

This is my simple plugin

```
jQuery.fn.numpad = function(options,callback) {

    var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            field: "#numpadInput",
            keys: "full",
            type: "numeric",
            width: "210"
        }, options );

    if(settings.keys == 'lock'){
        var numpad  = '<div id="numpadWrap" style="width:'+settings.width+'px" class="demo-button"> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">1</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">2</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">3</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">4</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">5</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">6</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">7</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">8</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">9</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">0</a></div> <div class="col-sm-8"><a class="btn btn-block delete btn-white btnNumpad"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></a></div> </div>';
    }else{
        var numpad  = '<div id="numpadWrap" style="width:'+settings.width+'px" class="demo-button"> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">1</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">2</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">3</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">%</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">4</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">5</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">6</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">.</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">7</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">8</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">9</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block delete btn-white btnNumpad"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">0</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">00</a></div> <div class="col-sm-6"><a class="btn btn-block clear btn-white btnNumpad">Clear</a></div>';
    }

    this.html(numpad);

    input = $(settings.field);
    input.attr('readonly',true);
    input.attr('type',settings.type);

    $('#numpadWrap a').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var key         = $(this),
            character   = key.text();



        // Delete
        if (key.hasClass('delete')) {
            var value = input.val();

            input.val(value.substr(0, value.length - 1));
            return false;
        }else if (key.hasClass('clear')) {      
            input.val('');
            return false;
        }

        // Add the character
        input.val(input.val() + character);
        callback();
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var options = {
                field: '#password',
                type: 'password',
                keys: 'lock',
                width: '200'
                };

    $('#numpad1').numpad(options);
```

In this case what it does is, attaches a numeric keyboard to the `DIV` `#numpad1`, then you can specify in the options the target input in which the pressed numbers are going to be displayed.

It works fine with only one element, but then, when I create a second instance the first one stops working properly. [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/qhyP4/3/)

Hope you guys can help me with this, thanks!!

Comment: The usual way to work with multiple elements is to put all your code inside a loop like this: `this.each(function(index, element) { your method code here})` so it iterates for each item in the collection.

Comment: not sure if I understand, where should I use `each` and what should I do with `index` and `element`?

Comment: I was about to post an answer with the body of your code inside a `this.each()` loop, but your code won't work with more than one element because you are inserting `<div id="numpadWrap"></div>` and you can only do that once since you can't have more than one element with a given ID.  So your code isn't designed to be used more than once without redesigning it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/THEtheChad/cAc7y/4/

```
$.fn.numpad = function(options, callback) {

    // defaults
    options = $.extend({
        field: "#numpadInput",
        keys: "full",
        type: "numeric",
        width: "210"
    }, options);


    if (options.keys == 'lock') {
        var numpad = '<div style="width:' + options.width + 'px" class="demo-button numpadWrap"> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">1</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">2</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">3</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">4</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">5</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">6</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">7</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">8</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">9</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">0</a></div> <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8"><a class="btn btn-block delete btn-default btn-numpad">Del</a></div> </div>';
    } else {
        var numpad = '<div style="width:' + options.width + 'px" class="demo-button numpadWrap"> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">1</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">2</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">3</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">%</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">4</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">5</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">6</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">.</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">7</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">8</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">9</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block delete btn-default btn-numpad">Del</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">0</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-numpad">00</a></div> <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><a class="btn btn-block clear btn-default btn-numpad">Clear</a></div>';
    }

    this.each(function(){
        var $input = $(options.field);
        $input.attr('readonly', true);
        $input.attr('type', options.type);

        var $numpad = $(this);
        $numpad.html(numpad);

        // use event delegates for added performance
        $numpad.on('click', 'a', function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();

            var $key = $(this),
                char = $key.text();

            // Delete
            if ($key.hasClass('delete')) {
                var val = $input.val();
                val = val.substr(0, val.length - 1);

                $input.val(val);
                return false;
            } else if ($key.hasClass('clear')) {
                $input.val('');
                return false;
            }

            // Add the character
            $input.val($input.val() + char);
            callback && callback();
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue a while ago and overcame it like this:

**Step 1:** write the whole plugin in a function

```
var numpadFunc = function(options,callback, element) {

    var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            field: "#numpadInput",
            keys: "full",
            type: "numeric",
            width: "210"
        }, options );

    if(settings.keys == 'lock'){
        var numpad  = '<div id="numpadWrap" style="width:'+settings.width+'px" class="demo-button"> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">1</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">2</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">3</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">4</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">5</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">6</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">7</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">8</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">9</a></div> <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">0</a></div> <div class="col-sm-8"><a class="btn btn-block delete btn-white btnNumpad"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></a></div> </div>';
    }else{
        var numpad  = '<div id="numpadWrap" style="width:'+settings.width+'px" class="demo-button"> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">1</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">2</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">3</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">%</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">4</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">5</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">6</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">.</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">7</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">8</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">9</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block delete btn-white btnNumpad"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">0</a></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="btn btn-block btn-white btnNumpad">00</a></div> <div class="col-sm-6"><a class="btn btn-block clear btn-white btnNumpad">Clear</a></div>';
    }

    element.html(numpad);

    input = $(settings.field);
    input.attr('readonly',true);
    input.attr('type',settings.type);

    $('#numpadWrap a').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var key         = $(element),
            character   = key.text();



        // Delete
        if (key.hasClass('delete')) {
            var value = input.val();

            input.val(value.substr(0, value.length - 1));
            return false;
        }else if (key.hasClass('clear')) {      
            input.val('');
            return false;
        }

        // Add the character
        input.val(input.val() + character);
        callback();
    });
}
```

**Step 2:** call your function inside your plugin

```
$.fn.numpad = function(options, callback){
    return $(this).each(function(){
        typingTextFunc(options, callback, this);
        });
    };
```

**NOTE:** any other problems you may face is caused by the function code, try maintaining it and have a look at my answer to my own question below, it may enlighten some ideas!

[assign jQuery plugin to multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067701/assign-jquery-plugin-to-multiple-elements)

Comment: Except the OP's code can't be run multiple times because they are inserted elements with an id and that would create conflicts.  Other redesign changes are required before the OP can run their code for a whole collection with `this.each()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I updated the JSFiddle implementing your suggestion but still no luck [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhyP4/5/) when I echo the actual element it always displays the latest called

Comment: now it's working as expected, right? as I mentioned any other issues are caused by the code, not the theory of multi-instance plugin writing!

Comment: Almost, the only problem I have is the plugin always takes the latest assigned element in both initialisations of the plugin, so no matter if I press the keys from the first plugin call or from the second, the result will always appear in the second input.

Comment: you forgot to define `input` variable as a local, so it was getting overwritten as a global variable! this line fixes it, `var input = $(settings.field);` see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/qhyP4/6/